# git client in linux not show http message

Tags: c, git, gitlab

git client in linux  show_http_message() not work

**setp1:**
in gitlab server(gitlab-workhorse/git/info-refs.go) ,i add some Http error return ,as:

```
http.Error(responseWriter, "Check user ip failed", 500)
return
```

**step2:**
when i clone repository in windows , i get the response:

```
C:\Users\mairongcong>git clone https://mygitlabserver/server/admin.git
Cloning into 'admin'...
remote: Check user ip failed
fatal: unable to access 'https://mygitlabserver/server/admin.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500
```

i can see  the  http error message "Check user ip failed",

**setp3:**
but when i clone repository in linux, i get the response

```
[root@localhost git-2.37.0]# git clone http://mygitlabserver/server/admin.git/
Cloning into 'admin'...
Username for 'http://mygitlabserver': mairongcong
Password for 'http://mairongcong@mygitlabserver':
fatal: unable to access 'http://mygitlabserver/server/admin.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500
```

i can not see the http error message like windows git  client "Check user ip failed"

i found the git client source , in remote-curl.c ，it seems that show_http_message() function not execute

can any one give me some suggest ,why linux git client can not see the http error message， thanks very much ,and forgive my poor english

Comment: There is comment on git sources   https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/http.c#L1496 this is an issue with curl not git

Comment: here the failonerror is set to 0 so no message https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/remote-curl.c#L1028